# IntelliJ IDEA not jumping to packaged Dart Classes

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, webstorm

I'm trying to build a demo application using Angular 2 Dart.

I'm using the Dart Plugin For WebStorm & IntelliJ Ultimate

I've tried a couple of the demo projects floating around the web, and none of the examples running above alpha 30 seem to have class support.

Example:

- git clone https://github.com/andresaraujo/ng2_dart_router_demo
- Open in Webstorm
- Run pub get to load dependencies
- Open main.dart
- hover mouse over bootstrap() method and try to step into it

**Problem**: I cannot step into even basic methods like bootstrap().

**Problem**: When running the Dart Debugger - breakpoints don't hit

**Question**: How do i enable jump to support for Angular 2 Dart in WebStorm or IDEA Ultimate?

*Note*: This is unrelated to TypeScript / JavaScript - Dart Specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current WebStorm/IntelliJ EAP version you need to run `pub get` `pub upgrade` from the command line.  WebStorm currently passes the experimental `--no-package-symlinks` option which breaks a few things. This was already changed and will be fixed with the next update. 
See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18020

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for filing [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18037) in JetBrains issue tracker! It is fixed now. Dart plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 15 EAP with the fix is published now (try Help | Check for Updates). WebStorm 11 EAP with the fix will be released next week.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different version of the SDK? I've had this problem previously and using a different one solved it (sometimes temporarily)

Comment: A newer SDK fixes it partially. The newest analyzer can work with the `.packages` file alone, some other tools might still depend on the `packages` directory and the symlinks.